# How to check if internal HDD spindle is off after unmount

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, battery, ssd, power

I use SSD instead of optical drive in my Macbook MC516LL, so I have bunch of reasons why I wants to keep HDD's spindle off:

- Preserve HDD from shock
- Reduce energy consuming
- Reduce overall system temperature

I use `diskutil umount HD250` and it disappears from OSx.
So how can I  check if spindle turned off?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diskutil umount HD250` - doesn't turn off spindle

**`diskutil eject HD250`** - turn off spindle

confirmd by sound and mA usage